# Are @name-only comments considered "fluff"?

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently was in a comment discussion on a question, and the user posted a comment consisting only of `@SylvesterKruin`. Are comments that contain `@name`, and nothing else, considered acceptable? Or are they considered "fluff", because they only exist to get attention? The user could have edited (or rewritten) their previous comment to contain `@SylvesterKruin`. Here is the link to the question with the comments: [How can I optimize my line movement in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69508991/16775594).

Comment: The user may not know that they can edit their own comment. I'm not sure what you mean by "are these comments okay?". You can definitely flag such comments as NLN.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a particularly useful comment. I'd flag as no longer needed and that's it. If the user keeps posting such comments, feel free to flag with a custom message for the mods.

Comment: A username shorter than 10 chars may circumvent the issue (an empty comment should not pass the form validation, to begin with). While on many other sites, it is rather considered a FYI "ping".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By design, all comments are considered fluff. If the only purpose of the comment was to notify a user of changes to the post, it is no longer needed as soon as that person sees it.

More importantly, Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. If the comment asks for clarification, then the correct response by the author should be an edit to the post and nothing else. Any comment that says something along the lines of "done", "updated", please check again", etc. is no longer needed as soon as it is posted. It's not necessary to gain the attention of the person who asked for clarification. If they are interested in updates to the post, they will follow it and get a notification.

The goal of comments is to ask for clarifications or point out ways in which the post can be improved. If you, as the author, address the comment, then please flag it as no longer needed.

**Do not ping other users to let them know you read their comments or updated your post!**

Comment: It's like calling someone to tell them you emailed them; just don't do it :).

Comment: TIL that you can follow a post. Always appreciated the followup comments (When they weren't just "plz halp now please")

Comment: *Do not ping other users to let them know you read their comments or updated your post* - so if I write an answer, and the OP says "how would I apply this to..", then I should neither a) say "i'll  make a edit to the answer, hold on.." or b) make an edit to the answer and then say "I added the relevant info to the answer" - because the *system* will notify them that I've made an edit to an answer they commented on, that answered their question? Really?

Comment: @CaiusJard Correct. That is how it should work. Once the comment has been addressed by an edit, you can flag it as NLN. Pinging the user doesn't provide any useful information. Of course, if you think you need to reply to the comment to explain why you made an edit or to clarify something else, then feel free to do so. Neither of your examples provides any value and such comments should be avoided.

Comment: @CaiusJard: It's totally normal to edit an answer after a comment points something out, then reply to that comment something like "@someone: thanks, fixed" or "added a section about that.".  Then after a few minutes / hours / days, delete your comment if it's adding nothing for future readers. You can even write "this comment will self-destruct" to let them know you're going to delete the comment after they see it, maybe also including "we can clean up our comments" if you want to encourage them to delete now-redundant comments. 100% disagree with Dharman's suggestion you shouldn't *ever* ping

Comment: (I can see the point in not pinging when it was just some other user pointing out a correction, not someone that needed your answer to be clearer for them to benefit from it.  In that case, the person making the correction doesn't need to know that you edited.  In low-traffic tags with a small community, I know the other frequent users so there's extra reason to respond: a semi-social interaction with one's SO colleagues.  As well as to arrange that we can delete our comments now instead of flagging for mods to deal with.)

Comment: @Dharman I asked a question in my comment; you appear to have answered it with something I do not believe to be true. I will carry on operating as Peter Cordes noted, because I do not believe that the system sends notifications to users that I have edited my answer after they commented, so I will use the comment to call the user back to the newly edited answer so they may benefit from the edit they requested in those cases where they needed it (they asked a question, rather than they pointed out a typo)

Comment: It would be wonderful if the NLN flag first informed the person who made the comment and then, after maybe a day of no action, promote the comment to some queue for dealing with, if the comment still exists. This would give us the opportunity to clean up our own comment trails without burdening queue reviewers, and avoid the "having to make a comment that their comment is NLN then they have to comment that mine is NLN" a chicken and egg we cannot escape from

Comment: I agree with the design and goal of comments, and have flagged many myself. But if *all* comments are fluff then why are they not just auto-deleted? I've found some comments useful years later.

Comment: @Kit Because the remarks have not been incorporated into the post. Sometimes, it's difficult to change the post to accommodate the remarks from comments. This leaves them in a perpetual state where they are still relevant years later. Until someone changes the post to make the comment no longer relevant, the comment has to stay. We can't auto-delete all comments, because the computer would have hard time deciding whether the comment has been incorporated into the post or not. The trivial comments (thanks, pings, please accept) are already removed automatically.

Comment: @CaiusJard It's usually easy to see when it is likely that a comment has been read by checking the last time the user was seen on the site. Oh, hang on....

Comment: @AndrewMorton There are user scripts posted on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) that will put that back on user profiles :)

Comment: When I downvote an answer and explain why in a comment, and the author then amends the answer to correct my reason for downvoting, if they don't also ping me, I will not know it was fixed and will not be able to undo my downvote or turn it into an upvote. Please do ping in these type of situation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You can ask to be pinged in the comment or you can follow the post. Either one works. Just be sure to clean up the comments when they are no longer needed

Answer (score 18):

The question "Are XYZ okay?" begs a metric for measuring "okay".

Ideally a commenter would include the `@name` tag in their initial comment.  If they forgot, they have a 5 minute window in which to edit.

When faced with this situation myself (wanting to tag someone after the 5-minute edit window) I've deleted the whole comment and added a new comment with the `@name` appended.  Is that better? I don't know.  Is it "okay"?  You tell me.

I can't see the cited comment in the linked question, so I assume it's been deleted, which is fine.  It can easily be flagged/deleted as "no longer needed".

So, is it "okay"?  For a new user, I presume so.  Answer and flag/delete the "no longer needed" comment.  Is it a pattern that regular users should get into?  Probably not.

Comment: Okay

Comment: Good answer! Just one thing: do you know whether `@name-only` comments are considered "fluff" by Stack Overflow? And yes, I think that rewriting the comment with the tag after the five-minute window is better than adding an extra `@name-only` comment after the initial comment.

Comment: "fluff" is really only germane to posts, where other people can edit the "fluff" out. Other people (except mods, IIRC) can't edit comments, so a designation as "fluff" is meaningless. I can insert as much fluff as I want in a comment. Others can flag those comments. That's as much interaction as is deemed necessary for comments.

Comment: A name-only comment is *content-free*, which would be my objection to it, not that it is "fluff". Comments that contain no relevant information can and should be removed, and the way to request that is by flagging them. Yes, editing the original comment within 5 minutes is preferred. So is deleting the original comment and reposting with the desired name notification. But sometimes people don't know how the site works. Or they make mistakes. Or maybe they want to ping two people, when the system allows only pinging one. None of these justify *leaving* the comment, though, so flag it. @syl